# materialize chips-autocomplete input color doesn't changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, materialize

I'm working on a rails application using materializecss gem.

here is some my code
application.scss: ( i added color)

```
@import "materialize/components/color";  
$primary-color: color("blue-grey", "base") !default;    
$secondary-color: color("brown", "base") !default;    
@import "materialize";
```

markup:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
</div>

<div class="chips chips-autocomplete"></div>
```

( I do initialize chips-autocomplete in script )
so i have two input tag, but i got some problem

div(input-field) color changed to brown.
but div(chips chips-autocomplete) color doesn't changed.(and if i select chips, chip's color doesn't changed, too)

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

2k17, I know but I just got the same question, so maybe someone else could came here and an answer could be usefull.

You did it right, but the `_variables.sass` does not take care of `$primary` nor `$secondary` colors variables.

The border and selected chip color are hard coded in file, you can view it here.

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/sass/components/_variables.scss#L130

As the library seems to be dead, you could fork it and fix it replacing

```
$chip-selected-color: #26a69a !default;
```

by

```
$chip-selected-color: $secondary-color !default;
```

Or if you don't want to change materialize files, overide colors in an `global.css` like so :

```css
.input-field .chips.focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #407ec9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #407ec9;
}
.input-field .chip:focus {
  background-color: #407ec9;
}
```